# How to build forked Angular Material 2 after npm install

Tags: angular-material2

I recently just created a forked repo of the Material2 angular repo and I want to use my version of the forked repo.

I have the right package and its getting installed fine. But the project is not built (missing the dist folder) and I am having a really hard to build the Material 2 project in the node_modules folder after npm install.

I am new to all the stuff.

Comment: Did you see the document titled `DEV_ENVIRONMENT.md`?

Comment: @Edric yes, however there is no guide on incorporating your own forked material project into an existing angular project.